# TERNARY CONDITIONAL OPERATOR does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-operator

i have this ternary:

```
{item?.orderItemStatus?.name === ('PROCESSED' || 'IN_TRANSIT') ? (
            <ReturnItemButton orderItem={item} />
          ) : null}
```

but it only seems to work for PROCESSED. If i change the status to IN_TRANSIT it returns the null.

Why?

Comment: It's the way the expression in `()` gets evaluated. Try `console.log( ('PROCESSED' || 'IN_TRANSIT'))` and you will see it always returns `'PROCESSED'` because it is truthy so you are always testing against that first string only

Answer (score 1):

The embedded if does not work that way

```
name === ('PROCESSED' || 'IN_TRANSIT')
```

is not working the way you expected because you need

```
name === 'PROCESSED' || name ==='IN_TRANSIT'
```

or

```
['PROCESSED','IN_TRANSIT'].includes(name)
```

This is more readable

```
const name = item?.orderItemStatus?.name ?? null;
....
{name && ['PROCESSED','IN_TRANSIT'].includes(name) ? (<ReturnItemButton orderItem={item} />) : null}
```

Comment: It is a valid js expression though. OP is not understanding how it gets evaluated

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```js
{ ["PROCESSED", "IN_TRANSIT"].includes(item?.orderItemStatus?.name) ? (
            <ReturnItemButton orderItem={item} />
          ) : null
}
```

Comment: That's right. You did.